# Child lightning component init execute before parent init salesforce

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I have a lightnoing  application App which contains a lightning component C1
This component contains an other C2 one which implements 2 dependent picklists
The issue is that C2 needs his attributes value from the C1 component
But since the Child component init (C2) is executed before the parent one init (C1), so the child is not working correctly
Can you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to this problem would be instead of using *init* handler you can use *change* handler in you **C2** component. So, the code will be something like,

```js
({
  doAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Access "data" using standard component.get()  
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- C1 component -->
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="dataForC2" type="Object"/>
  <c:C2 data = "{!v.dataForC2}"/>
</aura:component>

<!-- C2 component -->
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
  <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.data}" action="{!c.doAction}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to create one Boolean attribute for it when init method of parent is done  then make that one true so it can go for child init method

Note: use child  component inside aura:if in parent component